# Copy a pygraph, and modify nodes

Tags: python, pygraph

I have a [pygraph](https://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) data structure, which I want to modify. I want to perform the following operations:

1. Create a copy of the existing pygraph
2. Modify the nodes in the copy, by walking the tree and changing the node attributes

I am unable to find in the documentation/code how to do these operations. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

**Copying:**

To copy a structure in python you need to make use of the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

```
from copy import deepcopy
copy_graph = deepcopy(original_graph)
```

**Traversing**

There is an [example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) on how to traverse the graph:

```
from pygraph.algorithms.searching import depth_first_search
st, pre, post = depth_first_search(copy_graph)
```